# Setting variables depending on options

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to set variables depending on options using `<lightning-combobox>` but I'm getting a deploy failure. The code I m trying is the following

**JS**

```js
get timing() {
        return [
            { label: 'Weekly', this.minute= '0', this.hour='0', this.DoM='*', },
            { label: 'Monthly', this.minute= '0', this.hour='0', this.DoM='1',this.month='*',this.DoW='*'},
            { label: 'Code' },
        ];
    }
```

and for **HTML**

```html
<lightning-combobox placeholder="Time Set" options={timing}  onchange={handleTimeChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

Is there a method that i can use similaire to what i tried or am i obliged to set a value for the `lightning-combobox` and then create conditions depending on it

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your code. The corrected version is this:

```
get timing() {
        return [
            { label: 'Weekly', minute: '0', hour: '0', DoM: '*' },
            { label: 'Monthly', minute: '0', hour: '0', DoM: '1', month: '*', DoW: '*'},
            { label: 'Code' },
        ];
    }
```

If you’re using VS Code you should have seen red squiggly lines under that block.

If you’re using eslint it will fail.

If you’re not using both VS Code and eslint, I strongly recommend you use both. They make it trivial to identify and correct syntax errors like this.

Comment: Yeah i had red lines, will the minute: '0' value be set to be used in another JS function?

Comment: The code above returns a new object. It does not change any instance property.